# How to call javascript function inside the tag value in JSF markup

Tags: javascript, jsf

The markup I've written:

```
<a4j:commandLink reRender="reportTable" style="width:100%; height: 100%">
    <a4j:actionparam name = "orderedProperty" value = "realPlayers" />
    <a4j:actionparam name = "orderedProperty" value = "%toInvokeFoo()JavascriptFunctionHere%" />
</a4j:commandLink>

<script>
    function foo(){
        //Some JS code
    }
</script>
```

Is there a way to invoke JS function to pass the value it returns to the parameter?

Comment: please describe more!!!!!!!!   you can use This code if you can get value from backing bean  <param name="filePath" value="<h:outputText value= "#{backingBean.filePath}"/>">

Comment: @jubinPatel Is there a way to direct javascript function call without any usage of a backing bean.

Comment: As my Concerns it is not possible as you want :( lets hope someone get answer